# transpiling angularJs files in index.html

Tags: angularjs

My application comprises of two files.

```
//index.html
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="myController">

 Hello {{ foo }} 

<script src="app.js">
</body>
```

Javascript file:

```
 //app.js

  (function() {
    angular.module('app', [])
     .controller('myController', function($scope) {
           $scope.foo = 'World!';
     }
    })();
```

What I would like to do is use ES6 in app.js.

How do I include a transpiled version in index.html ?

Comment: give a transpiled file path on index.html.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is to use babel directly to transpile you ES6.js to ES5.js files.

For example, you can add all your *.js files to 'src' directory then run :

```
babel src --out-dir dist
```

And change like into your html to 'dist' directory. It is also possible to let babel concat all your js files into one. [The documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/)

Another possibility it to use already created build like [gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular). It is great to bootstra a project or understand how build works